# How to select all the first <td> of <tr>?

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's a part of the table,

```
<tbody id="list_tbody">
   <tr class="infoRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="infoRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="infoRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

the  tag continues...
and this is my jQuery code:

```
$("tr.infoRow td:eq(0)").css("border-left", "1px solid #d0d0d0");
```

How to select all the **first** `<td>` that is inside all the `<tr>`? On my current code, it only selects the first `<td>` of the first `<tr>`. Please correct my jQuery code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("tr.infoRow td:first-child").css("border-left", "1px solid #d0d0d0");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("tr.infoRow td::nth-child(1)").css("border-left", "1px solid #d0d0d0");
```

Note: nth-child is 1 indexed so you can pass some other number if you want to select any other column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nth-child` selector too:

```
$("tr.infoRow td:nth-child(1)").css("border-left", "1px solid #d0d0d0");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('table tr td:nth-child(n)').size()). It should show you '3'.
```

I think you need to change 'n' for 0 or 1. I don't remember. Check jQuery docs for nth-chi